# Docker volume not showing running linux container on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, volume, docker-volume, linux-containers

I am running Docker for Windows v19.03.12.  I am running a linux container from Windows 10.  I am sharing my entire c:\ drive with Docker (see image).  I am trying to testing a container locally and need to pass a credentials file to the container.

[image]

When I run the following command:

```
docker run --rm -p 9215:80 -p 44371:443 --name test -t createshipment:latest -v c:/temp:/data
```

When I explore the container I do not see a /data folder at all (see image).

[image]

I am not sure what else to try to share a folder when testing docker locally.

Comment: It's probably because you included the volume info after the image name. Can you try with `docker run --rm -p 9215:80 -p 44371:443 --name test -t -v c:/temp:/data  createshipment:latest` ? Note that `-t` allocates a pseudo-tty. It does not mean `--tag`, like it does in `docker build`.

Comment: You are 100% correct.  It worked.  If you post your answer below I will accept it.  I've spent 2 days on this, and you solved it in 5 minutes, Im extremely appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) expects the image name as the last argument, before any arguments to the image's entrypoint. In the OP's post, the image name precedes the `-v ...` argument, so `-v ...` is actually passed to the image's entrypoint.

```
docker run --rm -p 9215:80 -p 44371:443 --name test -t \
  -v c:/temp:/data createshipment:latest
```

For the sake of completeness, here are the relevant excerpts from the documentation for the command-line options used here:

```
Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

... 

    --name string     Assign a name to the container
-p, --publish list    Publish a container's port(s) to the host
    --rm              Automatically remove the container when it exits
-t, --tty             Allocate a pseudo-TTY
-v, --volume list     Bind mount a volume
```